# Auxiliary piping for shell input output redirection

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, io-redirection

In my script I need to output special commands to a pre-defined file descriptor along with usual stdout-stderr and listen to the commands in another program *without* creating a file.

Essentially it's like redirection with a pipe, but with a roundabout through using some other file descriptor(s) or socket or device:

Usual way with redirecting stdout(1) to stdin(0):

```
> program1 | program2
```

What I need (some redirection, which uses other descriptor e.g. 5):

```
> exec "open descr 5 <>5" 
> program1 ??5?? & program2 <5 &
```

program1 "knows" about the descriptor number 5 and just outputs to it with `fwrite(5, ...)`, program2 uses a usual stdin redrection.

How can I do this roundabout redirection in shell?

Comment: You need program1 to write to fd 5 and program2 to read from fd 5? So make a pipe/fifo?

Comment: The question description is too vague.  Which special commands are output?  What commands are being listened to, by which program?  If it _were_ possible to use files, how might it be done?   (NB: that last question is to give us a better grasp on the problem, not to give us an excuse to evade the problem.)

Answer (score 0):

You can't.  The only way to do anything like a semaphore is to use a fifo file, but you've said you don't want to make a file.  The file descriptors you define, will only exist in that shell, so any subprocess or another program would be unaware of them.